# Different output in GCC and Borland Turbo C for printf() statement

Tags: c, gcc, turbo-c

I have a small code in C

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a=10,b;
    b=a++ + ++a;
    printf("%d,%d,%d,%d",b,a++,a,++a);
    return 0;
}
```

Turbo C gives the following Output (as expected)

```
22,13,13,13
```

But GCC (used ubuntu and Code blocks compiler in windows) gives the following

```
22,13,14,14
```

I believe that Turbo c output was correct, but how come GCC is returning different output?

Comment: Regardless of the difference, never compare Turbo C to a modern compiler.

Comment: Why people upvoting this question. It has been asked 1000 of times.

Answer (score 4):

They both are correct! This is undefined behavior, because you arent allowed to change the same value in a single invokation multiple times.

From c99 ISO/IEC 9899:TC3 -> Apenndix J:

> J.2 Undefined behavior
>   1 The behavior is undefined in the following circumstances:

[...]

> — Between two sequence points, an object is modified more than once, or is modified
>   and the prior value is read other than to determine the value to be stored (6.5).

**EDIT:**

In reference to icepacks comment who told turbo c is predating c99, I added also the quote from the

C89 standard Programming Language C, X3.???-1988:

> A.6.2 Undefined behavior
>   The behavior in the following circumstances is undefined:

[..]

> - An object is modified more than once, or is modified and accessed other than to determine the new value, between two sequence points (3.3).

Comment: That's technically correct however Turbo C predates the C99 so it would be more correct to compare to C89.

Answer (score 2):

This is an undefined behaviour. As in C there is no specification of function argument evaluation, so the compiler is free to do it in any way. It is undefined and arbitrary.

C99 standard 6.5.:-

> Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its
>   stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression.
>   Furthermore, the prior value shall be read only to determine the value
>   to be stored.

Comment: -1 as you cant argument with C++ quotes to c standard question. C++ and C are diferent languages!!!

Comment: If it is asked in an examination, then I think abrupt nature of c compiler won't help in any way.

Comment: @GauravSharma:- That would definitely help. You can explain the reason too. Thats an undefined bahavior and its better to get that right to the examiner as well!!! :)

Comment: @Zaibis:- Thanks for that. Removed the C++ content!!

Comment: could you tell us please where the quote is from? just itnerested

Comment: @Zaibis:- Updated that in answer!! :)

Comment: @RahulTripathi can you explain how the output came `22,13,14,14` in GCC? how the increment of `a` took place and was printed?

Comment: @GauravSharma:- That is undefined and your compiler takes that in its way. You cannot predict that!!! That is why it is said as **UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR** Hope that makes sense!!

Comment: The section you quoted isn't what makes the behavior undefined. The relevant citation is section 6.5: "Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its stored value
modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression.
Furthermore, the prior value
shall be read only to determine the value to be stored." (That's C99; C11 uses different wording.) Not that it matters, since the question is a duplicate many times over.

Comment: @KeithThompson:- Thanks a lot Sir. Updated the same in my answer!!!